# How to retrieve information about BASIC authentication from JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, authentication

Client-side, is it possible to get information about the credentials, or the session, in a page that was retrieved via [basic access authentication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication)?

What we would like to do, ideally, is to get the username that was entered on the browser pop-up window when the user was prompted for their username and password.

Comment: You can create a API call that would return user data.

Comment: The server app that renders the page could include the username in its response.